# xubuntu 18.04 mouse and keyboard do not work with mousepad and System Monitor

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, mouse, system-monitor, mousepad

Mouse and keyboard input work normally with every other app (so far).

Launching mousepad app (/usr/bin/mousepad) results in a normal-looking window that won't accept input into the text area.  I can click on and use the keyboard to operate the menu.  Same effect if I right-click on a file and choose "open with".

This just started.  AFAIK nothing has changed for a week or so.

I have uninstalled and re-installed (dpkg --purge mousepad) to no avail.

Any ideas welcome.

This is Xubuntu 18.04

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
Linux nameHere 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

*ADDED 2018-12-27*
gnome-system-monitor (/usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor) is behaving the same way.  In addition, the list in the "processes" section is greyed-out (besides being unresponsive to clicks).

*ADDED 2019-01-19*
well, not ready to do a fresh install of xubuntu to fix this, and atom was not cutting it for my simple needs, so I purged mousepad and installed leafpad.  That seems to work OK so far. As a small note, I discovered I could paste into the edit area, but not type.  The settings options were mostly not available, too.  Booting the same hardware with an 18.04 rescue USB (full xubuntu install on a usb stick) results in normal mousepad behaviour.

I am also still stuck with gnome-system-monitor being useless, but it was just a bit more familiar than task-manager, so I canned gnome-system-monitor, too.

Wondering what else will come up and bite me.  Next hardware failure is guaranteed to generate a fresh install.

Comment: I have just discovered that the System Monitor app also displays the same behaviour.  That is, the scroll and sort functions do not work (nor does the display area in the processes "tab" respond to clicks), but the other control/menu functions do.

Comment: Can you try with a new user? Or, temporarily rename `~/.config` to something else, log out, log in and see if things work? A new `~/.config` folder will be created. If things work, you may carefully put folders back. Purging an application wouldn't remove config files stored in your home folder. So, if something went wrong @home, purging and re-installing would still use the old files in your home folder which may be the source of your problem.

Comment: no change in behaviour with either scenario (new user, and removing the ~/.config directory).  If I run mousepad with pkexec (i.e. as root) it functions normally, but with the as-expected warning I could harm my system.